# Knockout js disable button if parent hasClass

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to disable a button inside of a child div `if $("#parent").hasClass("bar");` **without** putting a `data-bind...` attribute on the actual button? Below is my code. I sense this is possible but I am not sure I am approaching it right:

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="parent" class="">
  <div class='active'>
    <button>Button 1</button> 
  </div>
<div>
```

**The JS**

```
function foo(){
  var self = this;   
  self.parent = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return $('#parent').hasClass('bar');       
  });
  if(self.parent){
    $('.active button').attr("disabled",true);
  }  
};
ko.applyBindings(foo);
```

The reason for this approach is that there are going to be many, many child divs but only one with the active class and I am concerned about binding all of them if I don't have to. Many thanks,

Comment: Like you're not hitting your marker for your  `self.parent` function.  You're going to have to use data-bind to achieve this.  haha I've been trying to solve this without any luck. It may be possible, but it's going to be hella hacky.

Comment: What do you mean by "marker?" Is that a knockout term?

Comment: it's not a term, I'm just saying you're not retrieving anything for `self.parent` it's just kind of like there but does nothing.

Comment: how is the active class set ?

Comment: By a simple jquery function that is not shown

Comment: you should implement the script to disable the buttons there

Comment: `if($('#parent').hasClass('bar')){
    $('.active button').attr("disabled",true);
  }` might as well do jquery.

Comment: Yes but that will only load it that way. I am trying to use Knockout because it will "watch" and dynamically disable when the class is added or removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about just using a subscription and stealing monkey_dev1300 jquery.

run snippet below.  and change the class from foo to bar.

```js
function viewModel(){
var self = this;
this.parentCss = ko.observable('foo');

}
var vm = new viewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.parentCss.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(newValue === 'bar')
    { $('.active button').attr("disabled",true); }
    else
    {{ $('.active button').attr("disabled",false); }}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
change class:  <input data-bind="value: parentCss"/>
</p>


<div id="parent" data-bind="css: parentCss"
  <div class='active'>
    <button >Button 1</button> 
  </div>
    <div class='active'>
    <button >Button 2</button> 
  </div>
   <div class='active'>
    <button >Button 3</button> 
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! How would this work if the input didn't exist, and instead I was toggling the class by using a separate buttons' click event? Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scooke/ub8ozbvf/29/

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/ub8ozbvf/31/   I think maybe your struggle is try not to use jquery. try to go for the knockout bindings where possible.  so you'll notice moving the click to the viewmodel as opposed to handling it in jquery allows the view model to update and then all the listeners can fire. if you try to handle stuff outside of the viewmodel you usually have to do a manual subscription.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to "disable" a button you can use this with JQuery and css:

```
$('button').css("pointer-events", "none");
```

This will stop the button from triggering click events.

Likewise you can 'enable' it with

```
$('button').css("pointer-events", "auto");
```

Comment: The question was about Knockout js, not jquery. Give that another read if you're interested.

Comment: Then remove the jquery tag

Comment: you still use jquery in your question